# How to parse a object to string in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

i have this code:

```
from subprocess import call
domain = input('input domain\n>>')
callme = 'whois %s ' % domain
data = call(callme, shell=True)
```

and when i try

```
print('TYPE OF DATA\n>>%s' % type(data))
```

it returns me

```
<class 'int'>
```

i need to manipulate the return but i cant parse this object. I tryied str() and repr() and json.loads() but none of those are working for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the *exit code* of the process. See the [`subprocess.call()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call):

> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then return the [`returncode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.returncode) attribute.

and for the linked `returncode` entry:

> The child return code, set by `poll()` and `wait()` (and indirectly by `communicate()`).

If you expected the output the process produces on stdout, you should use [`subprocess.run()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run), and set `stdout` to `subprocess.PIPE` so you can read that output in Python:

```
import subprocess

callme = 'whois %s ' % domain
proc = subprocess.run(callme, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
data = proc.stdout
```

This gives you a `bytes` object; you could set `text=True` to get a decoded string value.

Demo:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> proc = subprocess.run('whois stackoverflow.com', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
>>> proc.stdout.partition(b'\n')[0]
b'% IANA WHOIS server'
>>> proc = subprocess.run('whois stackoverflow.com', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
>>> print(*proc.stdout.splitlines()[57:74], sep='\n')
   Domain Name: STACKOVERFLOW.COM
   Registry Domain ID: 108907621_DOMAIN_COM-VRSN
   Registrar WHOIS Server: whois.name.com
   Registrar URL: http://www.name.com
   Updated Date: 2018-01-11T17:50:25Z
   Creation Date: 2003-12-26T19:18:07Z
   Registry Expiry Date: 2019-02-02T11:59:59Z
   Registrar: Name.com, Inc.
   Registrar IANA ID: 625
   Registrar Abuse Contact Email: abuse@name.com
   Registrar Abuse Contact Phone: 7202492374
   Domain Status: clientTransferProhibited https://icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
   Name Server: NS-1033.AWSDNS-01.ORG
   Name Server: NS-358.AWSDNS-44.COM
   Name Server: NS-CLOUD-E1.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
   Name Server: NS-CLOUD-E2.GOOGLEDOMAINS.COM
   DNSSEC: unsigned
```